# What's the point of having this unused function Init

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, initialization, getter-setter

New to C++, have a code with unused function Init, what's the point of having this if we never used it?

Header file: "KFilter.h"

```
#include "Eigen/Dense"
class KFilter {
  public:
    Eigen::VectorXd x_;
    KFilter();
    virtual ~KFilter();
    void Init(Eigen::VectorXd &x_in);
    void Predict();
}
```

cpp file: "KFilter.cpp"

```
#include "KFilter.h"
using Eigen::MatrixXd;
using Eigen::VectorXd;
KFilter::KFilter() {}
KFilter::~KFilter(){}
void KFilter::Init(VectorXd &x_in) {
    x_ = x_in;
}
void KFilter::Add_one() {
    x_ += 1;
}
```

Later in the main.cpp, I see someone use one object of this KFilter class.

```
KFilter ekf_;
ekf_.x_ = VectorXd(4);
ekf_.x_ < 1, 1, 1, 1;
ekf_.Add_one();
```

I guess it is kind of like setter and getter, but why Init? I couldn't find this kind of usage on the textbook of C++. Or it is because of the pointer used here?

Comment: It *is* a setter, probably intended to be used to initialize the object. Here the `x_` member is public so an assignment works just as well. Definitely not a textbook design. :-)

Comment: So, is it safe to say, even I remove Init in both header file and cpp file, the code will still perform correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The init function you are talking about is aconstructor. All classes have a constructor even if it isn't mentioned. In this case, instead of writing an empty comstructor you can write `Kfilter() = default;` or not write it at all.

In some cases this default constructor can be deleted, like for example if the class contains some members that aren't default constructible.

You can also delete this default constructor by writing `Kfilter() = delete;`, which would make that class not default onstructible.